# C# Windows store app: Enumerate childs of a griviewitem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I've trouble with this, how is it possible to enumerate childs of a gridviewitem object?

I've got a `GridView` that got some `GridViewItem` that contains a `StackPanel` that contains some `TextBlock`, like this:

```
foreach (var usr in list)
{
    GridViewItem item = new GridViewItem();
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = usr.name, Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black) });
    sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = usr.surname });
    sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = usr.company });
    SolidColorBrush blueBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkGray);
    item.Content = sp;
    item.Width = 200;
    item.Height = 200;
    item.Background = blueBrush;
    UsrGridView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

and the `foreach` will be like:

```
foreach(GridViewItem grvItem in UsrGridView.Items)
{
    foreach(object sp in grvItem.Content)
    {

    }
}
```

but, obviously, the code don't work, the error is in the second `foreach`, telling me that `object` doesn't contain a `GetEnumerator` function.

Thanks to anyone who can solve this.

Bye,

Fin3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast `GridViewItem.Content` to a `StackPanel` and then enumerate `StackPanel`'s `Children` (which implements `IEnumerable`), if your `StackPanel` contains only `TextBlock`s you can cast in the inner `foreach` as well:

```
foreach(GridViewItem grvItem in UsrGridView.Items)
{
    StackPanel sp = grvItem.Content as StackPanel;
    if (sp != null)
    {
        foreach(var c in sp.Children)
        {
            TextBlock tb = c as TextBlock;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was searching for...i'm a noob atm, but my intent is to grow up! From now to i will remember to do the cast before ask :) Thank you again! Fin3

Answer (score 0):

Use VisualTreeHelper. `element` is any UIElement:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( element ); i++ )
{
   var uiElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( element, i ) as UIElement;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried your way, but anyway i need to cast the result in order to read it content, anyway thank you! Fin3